# Editing Live Agent Supervisor Page

Tags: liveagent

Is it possible to edit columns in the Live agent Supervisor Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,  unfortunately is not possible to edit this page.

Comment: @highfive: How is my answer not providing an answer to the question? The OP asked if it was possible to edit the columns, I know for sure is not possible and that there is no workaround so it is a valid answer.

Comment: I think maybe its just the one sentence answer that sometimes causes people to question it.  It may be correct, but some additional details or elaboration sometimes helps.

Comment: No worries.  Now looking though, the question is one sentence as well, so maybe my comment doesn't exactly apply.  Either way, I think its a valid answer, I was more trying to guess as to why someone would claim it wasn't  valid.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce product management has confirmed numerous times when asked over the last few years that this page is not editable in anyway.   The bigger issue is there is no API access to the chat supervisor objects to be able to build your own more robust dashboard solution.